# rank of block triangular matrix with linear independence in sub-matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let's consider the $r \times c$ matrix:
\begin{equation*}
\left[ 
\begin{array}{ccc}
A & {B} & {C}%
\end{array}%
\right] =\left[ 
\begin{array}{ccc}
{A}_{1} & {B}_{1} & {0} \\ 
{A}_{2} & {B}_{2} & {C}_{2}%
\end{array}%
\right] 
\end{equation*}
where $A_1,(r_1 \times c_1)$ has full column rank, $B_1,(r_1 \times c_2)$ has full column rank and $A_1 x \neq B_1 y$ for any $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$. Assume that the number of rows of $[A, B]$ is larger than that of columns, i.e., $r>c_1+c_2$, but $r_1 \ge c_1+c_2$ does not necesarily hold.

Then,
(i) I conjecture that $rank[A,B,C] = rank[A,B]+rank[C]$ holds since any linear combination of $A_1$, $B_1$ and $[A_1, B_1]$ cannot be a zero vector.
(ii) I conjecture that $[A,B]$ has full column rank since $A_1 x \neq B_1 y$ for any $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$ and $r >c$.

I'm wondering if my above conjectures are correct. Any comments are appreciated! Thanks!